# How can i get the actual price of the product for a customer feed extension

Tags: magento

I am trying to get the actual price of the product for an feed, I can able to get the regular price of the product, but for some product i have dropdown selection with price-as-configure for those product my price is not synchronized for such product .

Please check the screenshot for more information :

For these type of  product i can able to get the price :
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/93901/bef62f7ea6f26130a719f4fa25876f3b

For these type of i can't able to get the price :
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/94069/294f8f9823179a35939fdf8dc8d2c594

Here is my observer.php

```
 $productData = array(
                    'SKU'               => $product->sku,
                    'Name'              => $product->name,
                    'ShopUrl'           => $product-> getProductUrl(),
                    'Description'       => $product->short_description,
                    'Currency'          => Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
                    'Price'             => number_format($product->price, 2, '.', ''),
                    'DiscountedPrice'   => $product-> special_price == null ? null : number_format($product-> special_price, 2, '.', ''),
                    'IsActive'          => ($product -> status) == 1 ? "true" : "false",
                    'Image'             => $productImage,
                    'Category'          => $productCategory,
                    'CategoryId'        => $productCategoryId
                );
```

Comment: are you using super attributes or configurable products?

Comment: I am using configurable products

Answer (score 1):

If you are using configurable products, you don't really want the parent product in your feed, so I would wrap your loop with something like this;

```
if( $_product->getTypeId() != 'configurable' ) {
// build the array
}
```

The simple products that represent the option choices will be included.  Be worth checking their names are useful - eg "Foo Shirt, Size 3, Blue"